# Is there any way to upload image with description of the image along with name and size in ReactS3Uploader

Tags: reactjs

Is there any way to upload image with description of the image along with name and size in ReactS3Uploader?

eg:-

```
OriginalName: Name.jpg,
Description: Nature Picture
```

Answer (score 1):

Amazon [supports adding custom metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-object-metadata.html#add-object-metadata-user-defined) through the `x-amz-meta-*` headers. The `ReactS3Uploader` component allows for passing custom headers like:

```
<ReactS3Uploader
  uploadRequestHeaders={{
    'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
    'x-amz-meta-my-tag': 'Foo',
  }}
/>
```

You can use this to set the headers you want (eg `x-amz-meta-original-name`).